# Best practice for dealing with package allocation in Go

Tags: memory, go, package, allocation

I'm writing a package which makes heavy use of buffers internally for temporary storage. I have a single global (but not exported) byte slice which I start with 1024 elements and grow by doubling as needed.

However, it's very possible that a user of my package would use it in such a way that caused a large buffer to be allocated, but then stop using the package, thus wasting a large amount of allocated heap space, and I would have no way of knowing whether to free the buffer (or, since this is Go, let it be GC'd).

I've thought of three possible solutions, none of which is ideal. My question is: are any of these solutions, or maybe ones I haven't thought of, standard practice in situations like this? Is there any standard practice? Any other ideas?

1. Screw it.

Oh well. It's too hard to deal with this, and leaving allocated memory lying around isn't *so* bad.

The problem with this approach is obvious: it doesn't solve the problem.

1. Exported "I'm done" or "Shrink internal memory usage" function.

Export a function which the user can call (and calling it intelligently is obviously up to them) which will free the internal storage used by the package.

The problem with this approach is twofold. First, it makes for a more complex, less clean interface to the user. Second, it may not be possible or practical for the user to know when calling such a function is wise, so it may be useless anyway.

1. Run a goroutine which frees the buffer after a certain period of the package going unused, or which shrinks the buffer (perhaps halving the length) whenever its size hasn't been increased in a while.

The problem with this approach is primarily that it puts unnecessary strain on the scheduler. Obviously a single goroutine isn't so bad, but if this were accepted practice, it wouldn't scale well if every package you imported were doing this under the hood. Also, if you have a time-sensitive application, you may not want code running when you're not aware of it (that is, you may assume that the package isn't doing any work when its functions are not being called - a reasonable assumption, I'd say).

So... any ideas?

**NOTE:** You can see the existing project [here](https://github.com/joshlf13/stringio) (the relevant code is only a few tens of lines).

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to this is letting the client pass an existing []byte (or whatever) as an argument to some call/function/method. For example:

```
// The returned slice may be a sub-slice of dst if dst was large enough
// to hold the entire encoded block. Otherwise, a newly allocated slice
// will be returned. It is valid to pass a nil dst.
func Foo(dst []byte, whatever Bar) (ret []byte, err error)
```

([Example](http://godoc.org/github.com/cznic/zappy#Encode))

Another approach is to get a new []byte from a, for example [cache](http://godoc.org/github.com/cznic/bufs#Buffers) and/or for example [pool](http://godoc.org/github.com/cznic/bufs#Cache) (if you prefer the later name for that concept) and rely on clients to return used buffers to such "recycle-bin".

BTW: You're doing it right by thinking about this. Where it's possible to reasonably reuse []byte buffers, there's a potential for lowering the GC load and thus making your program better performing. Sometimes the difference can be critical.

Comment: I don't think the "pass your own buffer" pattern works here because it's entirely internal (the user never sees the contents of the buffers). I'll look more into caches/pools, though; those look promising.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a single global (but not exported) byte slice which I start
>   with 1024 elements and grow by doubling as needed.

And there's your problem. You shouldn't have a global like this in your package.

Generally the best approach is to have an exported struct with attached functions. The buffer should reside in this struct unexported. That way the user can instantiate it and let the garbage collector clean it up when they let go of it.

You also want to avoid requiring globals like this as it can hamper unit tests. A unit test should be able to instantiate the exported struct, as the user can, and do it each time for every test.

Also depending on what kind of buffer you need, `bytes.Buffer` may be useful as it already provides `io.Reader` and `io.Writer` functions. `bytes.Buffer` also automatically grows and shrinks its buffer. In [buffer.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/bytes/buffer.go) you'll see various calls to `b.Truncate(0)` that does the shrinking with the comment "reset to recover space".

Comment: These buffers aren't ever touched by the user. The package implements a number of convenience functions, and the buffers are used for temporary storage. It's not the design pattern you're thinking of, I don't think.

Comment: @joshlf13 My advice still stands, regardless of the type of buffer. Don't use a global, give the user something to hold onto so the garbage collector can be used.

Comment: If I'm going to make the user deal with a more complex interface, I may as well just use the method of exporting a "free internal memory now" function.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/joshlf13/stringio) the code. It should give you a better sense of what I mean.

Comment: If you use a global buffer your code will not be thread-safe; what happens if two goroutines call your Read function at the same time? Please do not code this way.

Comment: @joshlf13 Why don't you just use bytes.Buffer? It does exactly what you're trying to do in a much safer way.

Comment: My problem isn't with the logic of how to expand and shrink buffers; I know how to do that. My problem is with when if ever they should be shrunk or freed so as not to use up memory.

Comment: bytes.Buffer's internal buffer is reused. It also automatically reclaims space.

Answer (score 0):

You could reslice your buffer at the end of every operation.

```
buffer = buffer[:0]
```

Then your function `extendAndSliceBuffer` would have the original backing array most likely available if it needs to grow.  If not, you would suffer a new allocation, which you might get anyway when you do `extendAndSliceBuffer`.

Overall, I think a cleaner solution is to do like @jnml said and let the users pass their own buffer if they care about performance.  If they don't care about performance, then you should not use a global var and simply allocate the buffer as you need and let it go when it gets out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally really really bad form to write Go code that is not thread-safe. If two different goroutines call functions that modify the buffer at the same time, who knows what state the buffer will be in when they finish? Just let the user provide a scratch-space buffer if they decide that the allocation performance is a bottleneck.